# How to Position Text and Icons on Top of a Video in html

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to insert a video clip in the html below as a background?  I'd like the title, icons, and feature to display on top of the video background.  I'd like to include the video in the html as shown below (or similarly)

```
<video width="1920" height="1000" autoplay muted loop playsinline id="vid">
    <source src="my-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<script>
    document.getElementById('vid').play();
</script>
```

I've tried absolute positioning, negative margin, and other approaches and it seems like the video element does not allow anything on top of it.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

```css
.hero {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
}

.hero-title {
    z-index: 20;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.hero-btm-area {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    z-index: 20;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.hero-icon {
    width: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="hero">
  <div class="container h-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="hero-title">
          <h1>Hero Title</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-auto hero-btm-area">
      <div class="col text-white text-center border-right border-white">
        <div class="hero-icon mx-auto">
          **Icon**
        </div>
        Feature One
      </div>
      <div class="col text-white text-center border-right border-white">
        <div class="hero-icon mx-auto">
          **Icon**
        </div>
        Feature Two
      </div>
      <div class="col text-white text-center">
        <div class="hero-icon mx-auto">
          **Icon**
        </div>
        Feature Three
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-bg-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the property of CSS called z-index.
z-index: -1 will put the video behind the background. You need to put position: absolute to put behind the content.

*Obs: I didn't understand the part of the top of video background, if I did something wrong, tell me please.*

```css
.hero {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
}

.hero-title {
    z-index: 20;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.hero-btm-area {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    z-index: 20;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.hero-icon {
    width: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#vid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<video width="1920" height="1000" autoplay muted loop playsinline id="vid">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<script>
    document.getElementById('vid').play();
</script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="hero">
  <div class="container h-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="hero-title">
          <h1>Hero Title</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-auto hero-btm-area">
      <div class="col text-white text-center border-right border-white">
        <div class="hero-icon mx-auto">
          **Icon**
        </div>
        Feature One
      </div>
      <div class="col text-white text-center border-right border-white">
        <div class="hero-icon mx-auto">
          **Icon**
        </div>
        Feature Two
      </div>
      <div class="col text-white text-center">
        <div class="hero-icon mx-auto">
          **Icon**
        </div>
        Feature Three
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-bg-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

*OBS 2: The video is strange because it's just a template, then u'll put your video*

Comment: This works, thank you.  Very simple adding the z-index and position to #vid.  I was trying to do similar things using classes and it made the code longer and was not working.  Thanks again.

Comment: :) Thanks for the comment :)
I'm so glad you like :)